# How to return my native android activity from flutter PlatformView (Android kotlin side)

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

How to return my native android activity from flutter PlatformView (Android kotlin side)
**here is my platformView class:**

```
class FlutterView internal constructor(context: Context?)
        : PlatformView {
    
        @Override
        override fun getView(): View {
            return  // here i need to return my activity view
        }
    
        @Override
        override fun dispose() {
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LayoutInflater` to create a `View` object from an XML layout and return it here. You can find from information [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29). After getting an instance of `LayoutInflater` from your preferred method from above documentation, you can write something like:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_activity_layout, null)
```